# Is the limit of this sequence zero or strictly positive?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits

I am looking at the following sequence: 
$$w_n=\sum_{k=2, k - even}^n \frac{1}{2^k} \binom{k}{k/2} \binom{n}{k} q^k (1-q)^{n-k},$$
where $q \in (0,1)$.

My conjecture is that the limit of $w_n$ is strictly positive but not sure how to prove it.

Any hints on how I can approach this problem in determining whether the limit is strictly positive would be helpful.

Comment: Notice that $\frac{1}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2} \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k}}$ as $k\to\infty$. Combining this with an appropriate concentration inequality (or with the intuition that the terms are only significant when $k \approx qn$), we can check that $w_n = \mathcal{O}(n^{-1/2})$ as $n\to\infty$, and in particular, $w_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Stirling's approximation, we can check that $\frac{1}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2} \sim \frac{c}{\sqrt{k}}$, where $c = \sqrt{2/\pi}$. Next, let

- $S_n \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,q)$, i.e., $\mathbf{P}(S_n = k) = \binom{n}{k}q^k(1-q)^{n-k}$ for $k = 0, \cdots, n$,
- $0 < \epsilon < \min\{q, 1-q\}$.

Then by the Chebyshev's inequality together with $\frac{1}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2} \leq 1$, we have

$$ \sum_{|k - qn| \geq \epsilon n} \frac{1}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2} \mathbf{P}(S_n = k)
\leq \mathbf{P}(|S_n - qn| \geq \epsilon n)
\leq \frac{q(1-q)}{\epsilon^2 n} $$

On the other hand,

$$ \sum_{|k - qn| < \epsilon n} \frac{1}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2} \mathbf{P}(S_n = k)
\leq \max_{|k - qn| < \epsilon n}\frac{1}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2}
\leq \frac{c + o(1)}{\sqrt{(q-\epsilon)n}}. $$

Combining altogether, we get $ w_n \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}} $ for some const $C > 0$ depending only on $q$ and $\epsilon$. So $w_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

---

**Addendum.** A more precise study shows that

$$ w_n \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi q n}} $$

as $n\to\infty$. The following plots compare both sides for $q = 1/3$ and $n = 2, 3, \cdots, 100$.

[image: Comparison of asymptotic form and actual values]